# 'Sigue mi cadencia pierdo la paciencia...' What is the meaning of this?

Tags: significado, letras-de-canciones

From the song *Eres para mí* by Julieta Venegas, what is the meaning of the following (bold text):

> **Sigue mi cadencia pierdo la paciencia**
>
> Tú eres para mí no te das cuenta

I'm not finding on the web any translations that are acceptable. In fact, I think all translations that I find are pulled from Google Translate!

Also, should there be a comma that separates 'Sigue mi cadencia' from 'pierdo la paciencia'?

By the way, learning this song (among others) has greatly improved my pronunciation. And learning Spanish by way of music makes it so much easier to remember vocabulary (individual words AND phrases). Everyone here at StackExchange is helping me acquire the proper meanings. Thanks so much!

Comment: Are you going to put your final performance on YouTube for Spanish SE to enjoy?

Comment: @mdewey  Hahaa, I hadn't thought about that - good idea. Okay, will do, and I'll update you when the video is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there should be a comma to separate those two sentences.

`Cadencia` means *cadence*, it's a synonym of *rhythm*, just like in english.

The rest I believe is quite straight forward:

> Sigue mi cadencia, pierdo la paciencia.
>
> *Follow my cadence (rhythm), I lose the patience*.

Comment: Ah, to paraphrase in the context of the song, "follow my lead and do what I've done, which is I've lost patience in delaying what I feel. You do the same, and just realize that we're made for each other."

Something like that. Thanks. This finally completes my understanding of the entire song. I'll keep practicing until I can sing the entire song without having to look at the lyrics (I'm about 70% there). Then on to the next song.